# Can I display the menu bar in full screen mode in Lion?

Tags: macos, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to always show menubar with fullscreen apps?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19160/how-to-always-show-menubar-with-fullscreen-apps)

Is there any way to always display menu bar in full screen mode in Lion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

An alternative way is like, create a new Desktop, move the application you want to full screen into that new Desktop, and make that application screen as big as the Desktop.  So, you have a dedicated Desktop for that application, full screen, and with the menu bar.

Comment: Thanks. That's bit of a hassle, and hope there's a terminal hack to do this soon.