# Always show menubar in full screen applications

Tags: macos, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to always show menubar with fullscreen apps?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19160/how-to-always-show-menubar-with-fullscreen-apps)

Is there a way to force full screen applications to show the menubar without having to mouse over it? I am irritated by the way that full screen chrome will have its tabs sometimes covered up by the lowered menubar when I didn't intend to open the menu.

Comment: Also see these two SuperUser questions: [Mac OS Lion - Always show menubar with fullscreen apps?](http://superuser.com/questions/316438/mac-os-lion-always-show-menubar-with-fullscreen-apps) and [Keep menu bar even in full screen mode?](http://superuser.com/questions/302604/keep-menu-bar-even-in-full-screen-mode)

Comment: It might be better to suggest an edit to the previous question if your use case (chrome UI layout) isn't obvious from the wording of the previous question. I think that might make the first question better.

Comment: @DMan - please comment on the linked question - those are nice to have on the question that's open and I can't mod it over there with the tools given to me.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of fullscreen is to hide all the distractions. So the short answer is no. Unfortunately, there's no way of keeping the menu bar or the dock, while in fullscreen mode.

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted?