# OSX Yosemite full screen menu bar

Tags: macos, menu-bar, fullscreen

Is there a way to always keep the menu bar visible in full screen mode?

When developing I like having certain applications take up the full screen but I find the delay in bringing down the menu bar slightly annoying. I'd like the menu bar to be always visible. I followed the answers from [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19160/how-to-always-show-menubar-with-fullscreen-apps) but changing the LSUIPresentationMode did not do anything.

If anyone has a working solution I'd be happy to try it out!

Thanks!

Comment: Not that I know of - wouldn't just maximised do instead? Or learn the key-commands?

Comment: I guess I'd like ability to have the screen's full real estate (no dock) but the menu available. I guess I will have to compromise. Thanks!

Comment: You could set the doc to autohide and then maximize the app window.

Comment: Does any of these answers keep the separate "desktop space" page when entering the maximized window state? Seems to just maximize it within the current space :(

Answer (score 5):

Like @james_fuller said auto-hiding the doc and maximizing the app window (use the `alt` key when clicking maximize) will have the requested result. Some apps (Google Chrome) have custom behavior for the maximize button so Shiftit.app can be used to maximize those apps with a simple key command.

Answer (score 1):

I use Moom and works pretty good:

http://manytricks.com/moom/

It allows you to maximize to fullscreen but keeping the menubar still visible. Different than clicking the green button on the window which enters fullscreen.

Comment: That's a paid app. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

Alt+Click on the green full screen button does the same as that when **Double click** the app menu bar

Answer (score 0):

To add the toolbar and keep it there when maximizing the screen I used the option and taped the pad. I was surprised.

Answer (score -1):

Press **shift** & **alt/option** and click on the green maximize button.

Comment: This was one of the huge annoyances that kept me from upgrading from Mavericks for the longest while. In fact, one of the reasons why I skipped Yosemite entirely. Well, that and various bugs that had to be worked out with a major OS X version, and the fact that the Helvetica kerning / letterspacing looked completely **wrong**. So, a year and a half later of debugging and actually hiring typographers at Apple, I'm back on board again.

Comment: This does not maximise use the other answers for that

Comment: I don't see any difference between alt/click & shift/alt/click