# Is there a way to make the Menu bar show at all times in fullscreen windows?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, fullscreen

I'm new to macOS and I really like the way you can assign a window to be it's own Desktop via full-screening. However, I have an issue with the default way the Menu bar works in full-screen.

I often move my cursor to the top of the screen to click on my tabs in my browsers and editors, and accidentally trigger the Menu bar obscuring my tabs. Other times I'd like the Menu bar to be available at a glance rather than having to trigger it by mousing up.

Is there some setting or application that will force the Menu bar to show at all times for full-screened windows?

It appears I'm not the first to have this issue, but the solutions in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19160/how-to-always-show-menubar-with-fullscreen-apps) didn't work for me and based on the comment for the top answer it won't work for anyone.

If there is no way to do this can anyone give me a hint where I can get started writing an application to do this?

PS: Please don't suggest that I simply hold alt when clicking the fullscreen green button or anything else like just resize the window to fill the screen". This doesn't solve my issue because it strips away many of the advantages of fullscreening.

Comment: If you like the isolation of multiple desktops and being able to swipe between them etc, have you considered just adding the "maximised" version of the application to a new space/desktop? As "full screen" is "full screen" its not "full screen minus a bit" otherwise many people could get frustrated that full screen is not full screen :P - You say you lose advantages of fullscreening, maybe if you could elaborate on these advantages you want then would be easier suggest things

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "the advantages of fullscreening" please?

Comment: this issue (accidentally revealing the menu bar while aiming to click a browser tab) drives me mad.. unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a solution as yet - all answers below suggest avoiding full-screen Spaces mode altogether, which is not what I what..

Comment: Such a simple solution that apple could provide is a checkbox in Space

√ Maintain Menu Bar when in Full Screen Mode.

Come on Apple, give us options, not restrictions!!

Comment: One advantage of fullscreen mode - web browsers are easily tracked/profiled by viewport. When you're not in fullscreen, your viewport depends on things like location and size of your dock. You become pretty unique.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is possible in **macOS 12 Monterrey**!!

In **System Preferences** ❭ **Dock & Menu Bar** ❭ **Dock & Menu Bar**, under the "**Menu Bar**" section at the bottom, you'll find this beautiful and glorious check box:

[image: Here's a screenshot showing off the "Dock & Menu Bar" panel of System Preferences in macOS Monterrey, with the "Dock & Menu Bar" section selected, and an arrow pointing at a checkbox labelled "Automatically hide and show the menu bar in full screen".]

Simply uncheck that box, and now when you bring an app into full-screen, the menu bar will remain at the top of the screen!

[image: Then, a screenshot showing off Safari in full-screen mode, with the menu bar showing at the top of the screen.]

The only strange thing to be aware of is the window control buttons (the "traffic lights"). Just like with this preference checked, the control buttons won't show until you bring your cursor to the top of the screen. This behavior strikes me as odd, but understandable, so I figured I'd note it here.

[image: Here's an animation demonstrating the behavior described above.]

---

## This answer was outdated!

> Since I still think there's merit in [the old answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/177126/3), I've archived it here:

> I've been annoyed by this, too, and the simple, yet very, *very* painful answer is to hold <kbd>alt ⌥
> option</kbd> and press the green title bar button (which should turn into a + when you hold option/alt)
>  
>  [image]
>  
>  If this doesn't make it cover the screen, you can finish the job by holding <kbd>alt ⌥
> option</kbd> and double-clicking a corner to resize the window to fill the screen.
>  
>  If you make your dock hide by default, this essentially gives you a "fullscreen" program with the menu bar always shown.

Comment: This is a great solution. However it doesn't work in split screen mode.

Comment: @dorien yep. Another reason I'm disappointed. Apple can do better.

Comment: @Supuhstar Indeed. Also making a maximized window a separate desktop seems overkill. You can't have windows on top then if you want to float them over it.

Comment: @dorien - what makes you think that? In fact it's the opposite - a fullscreen app will take up the whole Space, a maximised one can have other apps/windows over it, if desired.

Comment: @Tetsujin You are right, sorry. Now just a way to maximize to split view easily.

Comment: For that, I don't know, sorry. Split view is something I can't ever anticipate using. 2x 27" monitors... you don't really need it ;)

Comment: If you don't already, you can use a 3rd-Party tool like [Hyperdock ($10)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hyperdock/id449830122?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo%3D4) or [Spectacle ($0)](https://www.spectacleapp.com/), which implement Windows-style window snapping. Note that the system doesn't expect these and some weirdness might occur.

Comment: Doesn't work if you run MacOS in a VM. It just grabs the window of my VM software.

Comment: @AaronFranke this works for me in Parallels. What VM software are you using?

Comment: @BenLeggiero VirtualBox on a Linux host

Comment: @AaronFranke Sounds like [a VirtualBox bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker) :)

Comment: Still, quite annoying that there's only one way to maximize windows.

Comment: @BenLeggiero How did you make this super high resolution screenshot?

Comment: @Codey I just used ⌘⇧4 when the window was on my retina display

Answer (score 15):

In addition to what others have said (using the `ALT/OPTION + CLICK` green maximize button), to designate a Desktop Space for one app, you can do a:

- **3 (or 4) Finger Swipe Up** to bring up the spaces menu at the top of the screen.
- Bring your mouse over the top right and the (+) icon should expand and let you add a new space.
- Drag that space in whichever order you desire (first, second, or last, etc.)
- Now you can drag your desired app into that space, and (if it's not already...) you can maximize it with the usual keyboard shortcut trick.

It's worth noting that although `ALT/OPTION + CLICK`-ing the green maximize button does expand the window to full height, you probably want to combine it as `SHIFT + ALT/OPTION + CLICK` to expand to full width and height of your screen.

[image: Add your own Desktop Space manually]

Happy Spacing & Maximizing!

Answer (score 12):

This is possible in **macOS 12 Monterrey**!!

In **System Preferences** ❭ **Dock & Menu Bar** ❭ **Dock & Menu Bar**, under the "**Menu Bar**" section at the bottom, you'll find this beautiful and glorious check box:

[image: Here's a screenshot showing off the "Dock & Menu Bar" panel of System Preferences in macOS Monterrey, with the "Dock & Menu Bar" section selected, and an arrow pointing at a checkbox labelled "Automatically hide and show the menu bar in full screen".]

Simply uncheck that box, and now when you bring an app into full-screen, the menu bar will remain at the top of the screen!

[image: Then, a screenshot showing off Safari in full-screen mode, with the menu bar showing at the top of the screen.]

The only strange thing to be aware of is the window control buttons (the "traffic lights"). Just like with this preference checked, the control buttons won't show until you bring your cursor to the top of the screen. This behavior strikes me as odd, but understandable, so I figured I'd note it here.

[image: Here's an animation demonstrating the behavior described above.]

Comment: Just FYI, you have to logout and log back in for the changes to take effect

Comment: Not for me, @LucaKiebel. Though, I did have to take the application out of fullscreen and put it back in. Which app(s) is/are giving you this trouble that it's not obeying this setting until relogging?

Answer (score 6):

I use [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai) in two ways.

First, I defined an action that right clicking the maximize button will maximise windows rather than trigger fullscreen mode. Of course, you can set your own action or key combination instead or even override the green button entirely.

[image]

Second, I use [Window Snapping](https://docs.bettertouchtool.net/docs/101_window_snapping.html), which basically imitates the functionality in Microsoft Windows. When you drag a window into a corner or to the top of the screen it will either enlarge it to an area of the screen or maximize it, respectively.

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Your link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

**This might be a useful piece of info as an alternative to the other suggested options or for different use cases**

**<kbd>Double Click</kbd>ing the window title bar may also maximize the window size**, keeping the menu bar and the dock visible.
However, this is *only true for some applications*. As stated correctly by Ky, this action might also just resize the window to a size *the application sees fit*.

Comment: Unfortunately, some applications (like Safari and Finder) don't maximize the window when you do this ☹️

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>-<kbd>⌥ opt</kbd>-click on the green stoplight button (+) to maximize the window in both width and height, keeping the menu bar visible.

Comment: What does ⇧ do in this case?

Comment: @BenLeggiero, the `+` button is actually called Zoom, and [it resizes the window to fit the *content*](http://www.macyourself.com/2011/02/06/why-doesnt-mac-os-xs-green-zoom-button-maximize-windows/), not the *screen*. This is the case in every version before Full Screen replaced Zoom. ALT-clicking `+` would serve as Maximise. For many third-party apps, macOS decides that the right size to fit the content is to use as much space as possible, but other apps take full advantage of the Zoom button's intended use. After Full Screen replaced Zoom, Zoom became ALT-click, and Maximise ALT-SHIFT-click.

Comment: @JivanPal I tried `⌥`-`⇧`-clicking the green button in Finder, and it behaved the same as `⌥`-clicking

Comment: @BenLeggiero, interesting, I just tried it too on Catalina 10.15.6, and it also doesn't do anything. I do remember this working on older versions of macOS, so I guess the feature has been removed.